# Janusgraph 1.0.0 with cassandra backend : Error No serializers

Tags: janusgraph, gremlin-server

When trying to setup janusgraph 1.0.0 with CS & ES backend i am getting following error :

```
13:01:23 ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer.configureSerializers - No serializers were successfully configured - server will not start.
13:01:23 ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.start - Gremlin Server Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization configuration error.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer.configureSerializers(AbstractChannelizer.java:294) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer.init(AbstractChannelizer.java:144) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer.init(WebSocketChannelizer.java:67) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.start(GremlinServer.java:167) [gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.start(JanusGraphServer.java:98) [janusgraph-server-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.main(JanusGraphServer.java:53) [janusgraph-server-1.0.0.jar:?]
13:01:23 ERROR org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.lambda$main$0 - JanusGraph Server was unable to start and will now begin shutdown
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization configuration error.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAcceptAsync(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.start(JanusGraphServer.java:99) ~[janusgraph-server-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.main(JanusGraphServer.java:53) [janusgraph-server-1.0.0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization configuration error.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer.configureSerializers(AbstractChannelizer.java:294) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer.init(AbstractChannelizer.java:144) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer.init(WebSocketChannelizer.java:67) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.start(GremlinServer.java:167) ~[gremlin-server-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.start(JanusGraphServer.java:98) ~[janusgraph-server-1.0.0.jar:?]
    ... 1 more
13:01:23 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$stop$2 - Shutting down OpProcessor[]
13:01:23 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$stop$2 - Shutting down OpProcessor[session]
13:01:23 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$stop$2 - Shutting down OpProcessor[traversal]
13:01:23 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.stop - Shutting down thread poo
```

Any guidelines would help.

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: Please add information about the steps you performed to get these errors. Did you use the Docker image or the zip archive? If you are not using Docker, then what Java version are you using? How does your config look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing a quite similar problem when upgrading Janusgraph from v0.6.0 to v1.0.0. Please check below all errors I am getting back as soon as I start the service (janusgraph.service)

```
ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer.configureSerializers - No serializers were successfully configured - server will not start.

ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.start - Gremlin Server Error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization configuration error.
ERROR org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer.lambda$main$0 - JanusGraph Server was unable to start and will now begin shutdown

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization configuration error.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization configuration error.
```

Please check my `gremlin-server.yaml` serializers status as well.

```
 serializers:
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  # Older serialization versions for backwards compatibility:
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONUntypedMessageSerializerV1, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to solve the problem myself. Check the below if needed!

```
#
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  # Older serialization versions for backwards compatibility:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.ser.GraphSONUntypedMessageSerializerV1, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
```